# Modifying object property located in State

Tags: reactjs

I have learned that in order to modify a property or child object located in state, you cannot set it directly in setState. Instead, I need to create a copy of the object in my function and modify it there first. What I was then doing was returning the entire change object using setState as seen below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
        this.state = {
            item: this.props.item,
            success: false
        }
}
```

and:

```
handleChange(event){
    let item = this.state.item;

    const target = event.target;
    let value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const id = target.id;

    item[id] = value;

    this.setState({
        item: item,
        success: true
    })
}
```

One thing I did not realize, however, is that objects are copied by reference. Which means that the line `item[id] = value` automatically updates the state. Is there any harm then with removing the `item: item` line from the setState function as follows?

```
    this.setState({
        success: true
    })
```

Question 1: It works just fine like this, but are there any side effects with doing it this way?

Question 2: On the other hand, is there any harm keeping the original setState the way it was? Since `item` was already updated in state, it doesn't seem like there should be any harm in updating it again.

Question 3: Would it make more sense to make a complete copy of the object instead first and therefore avoid this entire issue such as the following:

```
let item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.item));
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have learned that in order to modify a property or child object located in state, you cannot set it directly in setState. Instead, I need to create a copy of the object in my function and modify it there first.

**You are not forced to do this way.** It's a common practice to do that because this way you could use shallow comparisons to know when something has changed and optimizing render performances. I highly suggest you to read this paragraphs of the official guide to understand what I'm talking about:

- [Avoid Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation)
- [shouldComponentUpdate In Action](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action)
- [The Power Of Not Mutating Data](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data)
- [Using Immutable Data Structures](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#using-immutable-data-structures)

That said:

> One thing I did not realize, however, is that objects are copied by reference. Which means that the line item[id] = value automatically updates the state.
>   Question 1: It works just fine like this, but are there any side effects with doing it this way?

Objects are copied by reference, yes, and so `item[id] = value` do change the state value. But **does not automatically trigger a re-render of your component**. So, state changes, but your views do not reflect that change. It does work in your case because after that instruction, you make a call to `setState`, which is a function that changes the state (again) **and** trigger a re-render. If you don't (or don't need to) call `setState` after, you **need** to call `this.forceUpdate()` to trigger a re-render, and your views will reflect that "manual" state change.

> Question 2: On the other hand, is there any harm keeping the original setState the way it was? Since item was already updated in state, it doesn't seem like there should be any harm in updating it again.

This question makes no sense at this point. Now it should be clear to you what happens.

> Question 3: Would it make more sense to make a complete copy of the object instead first and therefore avoid this entire issue such as the following

Makes sense regarding the stuff in the manual I linked to you before. However making a copy of the object using JSON encoding is quite useless. There are better ways, described in that links.

Hope I was clear and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you [this article](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/08/pros-and-cons-of-using-immutability-with-react-js/). Besides that, instead of stringifing and parsing that object, you may use `const item = { ...this.state.item }`. If you notice that, I've used `const` instead of `let`. `const` definitions would be fine until you try to change whole variable with a new value. I mean it's fine if you just update a property of that const variable which is an object.

According to that mutable react state, I'd say it's not ideal. Because React checks variable reference. In your case, reference isn't changed. But virtual DOM gets difference because of `success`.